# How to use CPAN modules in Perl Mason?

Tags: perl, mason

I want to use a CPAN library.
Where do I add this line `use Data::UUID;`in a Mason file?

Answer (score 0):

In your file.pl which serves Mason requests.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Mason;
use Data::UUID;
my $mason = Mason->new(comp_root => '...');
print $mason->run('/foo')->output;
```

Comment: I believe I saw an example that showed them used in the template too, just like any other code. Can you confirm?

Comment: What does this line do? Mason->new(comp_root => '...');

Comment: There won't necessarily be a separate Mason serving Perl script depending on the config. But that doesn't matter because you can just stick the `use` lines in the `<%init>` block of your template. (Though it's probably better to use `<%once>` instead.)

Comment: It's just an example code from man Mason. That code does nothing.